# imap_list() in PHP not showing me my "Additional Mailbox"

Tags: php, exchange-server, imap

I am trying to connect to the inbox of an "Additional Mailbox" on a Microsoft Exchange server. Connecting to my server and running imap_list does NOT show the mailbox, but it is listed using Outlook. I see the rest of my folders though.

```
$mbox = imap_open( '{mail.domain.net:143}', 'username', 'password' );

echo '<pre>';
echo "<h1>Mailboxes</h1>\n";
$folders = imap_list($mbox, "{mail.domain.net:143}", "*");

if ($folders == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($folders as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMAP has no access to this data. Outlook is getting it through AutoDiscover and opening the additional stores via MAPI.

Comment: My eventual solution was to use Exchange Web Services